# Joining four mySQL tables without a single common value

Tags: mysql

I have four tables that I need to pull data from. Three of the tables have a common value (product_id) the fourth table has a value in common with the third table (category_id). So they look something like this:

Products: 
product_id, name, quantity, image, weight

Product_Description: 
product_id, Description

Product_to_Category: 
product_id, category_id

Category: 
category_id, category_name

I need to pull all of the data and combine it into a result that looks like this
Name, Quantity, Image, Weight, Description, Category name

I know how to do a JOIN that works for the first three tables but I don't know how to add the into the results.

Comment: Start by writing as much of the join as you can in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an additional `join` on the `category_id`:

```
select p.name, p.quantity, p.image, p.weight, pd.description, c.category_name
from products p 
    join product_description pd on p.product_id = pd.product_id
    join Product_to_Category pc on p.product_id = pc.product_id
    join category c on pc.category_id = c.category_id
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)